# Who can edit "on hold' questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, on-hold

Who can edit "on hold" questions? My guess is users with more than 2K reputations and OP himself, is that correct?

Comment: There's nothing special with editing "on hold" or closed questions; the normal editing rules apply.

Comment: Short version: no change from the usual.

Comment: What made you think that editing a closed/on hold question is any different than editing any other question?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - There is no specification about closed questions in "How does editing work" (may be you can do it :)). However, I have edited another question.

Comment: @hims056 closed question is still a question, so the question here is equal to "Who can edit questions"? thus the faq is relevant. Not sure what you mean by "I have edited another question"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - By that I mean I have edited another [duplicate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/187824).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question asker can edit the question.

Additionally, anyone with the [edit privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) can edit it.

Others can suggest edits, which the community can approve or reject (via the review queues).

Comment: Does this policy apply to "closed' questions?

Comment: @AveMaleficum - the two are the same. An question that is "on hold" is in fact a closed question - it just has the "on hold" label for 5 days (as it appears less final and there is a better chance that the OP will actually edit it into a better question).

Comment: @Oded, Is it true that users < 2K reputation can't edit "on hold" question ?

Comment: @Kedarnath - Only in that users < 2K (i.e those without the "edit" privilege) can't edit **any** post, but only suggest edits.

Comment: @Oded Sir, can user with 10k reputations edit "closed" questions?

Comment: @AveMaleficum - I would think that was answered by my answer and the comments on it. It it really that difficult to understand? Posts that are either "open", closed or on-hold can be edited by their poster and people with the "edit" privilege (which 10k users have).

Comment: @Oded No, sir, the "deleted" questions, not the closed questions.

Comment: @AveMaleficum - You wrote "closed", not "deleted". And 10k users _can_ edit deleted posts.

Comment: @Oded A thousand thanks.